# How to rearrange columns

Tags: awk, gawk

In a file I am reformatting, I would like to put the last column as the first and have the rest of the columns stay the same.  I could do this easily in python, but thought I'd learn some awk this evening.

Here is an example:

(before)

```
polk_describes:1 diatribe_that:1 #label#:negative
```

(after)

```
#label#:negative polk_describes:1 diatribe_that:1
```

However, there are many more than 3 columns. In fact the column count varies.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make assignments to fields, and thus clear them:

```
awk '{ lastfield = $NF; $NF = ""; print lastfield " " $0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
% echo 'polk_describes:1 diatribe_that:1 #label#:negative' | \
  awk '{ print $NF " " substr($0, 1, length($0) - length($NF)) }'
#label#:negative polk_describes:1 diatribe_that:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print $0 but delete the last couple of fields?  Just like you can assign to a field to change $0 automagically, you can assign to NF to delete the last field(s).

```
{ NF = NF - 2 ; print "All but the last two: " $) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  print $(NF), $1, $2, $3, $4  # etc. to the max number of columns
```

can also be written in a loop which is more elegant and precise, regarding the number of colums.  (also see Nicholas Riley's trick in this post, to truncate the last field out of $0 and printing it at once).